How to set the initial value of 'mutableIntStateOf()' to a value that is fetched from a viewstate?
I have a composable that gets populated using an initial value that comes from an API until a user sets the value to something different.
I have this method to handle passing the user entered data from one screen to the screen i want to display it on and it works:
object ModellerSharedData {
    // todo make sure the initial value is the initial age
    private var _userInputtedRetirementAge = mutableIntStateOf(0)

    var UserInputtedRetirementAge: Int
        get() = _userInputtedRetirementAge.intValue
        set(value) {
            _userInputtedRetirementAge.intValue = value
        }
    val userInputtedRetirementAge get() = _userInputtedRetirementAge
}

I have a viewmodel that handles getting the API initial value and it also works just fine:
init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            personalProjectionsRepository.projectionsStateFlow
                //...
                .collect {
                    viewState.value = ModellerInitialViewState(
                        initialRetirementAge = repo.age
                    )
                }
        }
    }

fun getUserInputtedRetirementAge(): Int {
    return ModellerSharedData.userInputtedRetirementAge.intValue
}

fun getUserInputtedMonthlyContributions(): Int {
    return ModellerSharedData.userInputtedContributions.intValue
}

ViewState:
data class ModellerInitialViewState(
    val initialRetirementAge: Int,
) : ViewState

Here's the composable:
MakeChangeCard(
                cardTitle = R.string.retirement_age_screen_title,
                editLinkText = R.string.edit_link,
                cardContent = if (initialRetirementAge != userInputtedRetirementAge) {
                    userInputtedRetirementAge.toString()
                } else { initialRetirementAge.toString() },
                onCardClick = onRetirementCardClick,
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )

Putting the 2 together is where i get issues. I can display the user inputted age just fine, and i can also display the API just fine, but what i want to happen is a conditional where the api age is displayed at the start and then when the user changes the age, the user inputted one is displayed if it's different from the initial one.
At the moment what happens is that at the start the age is not the API one, it's 0, which i'm expecting because of this:
// todo make sure the initial value is the initial age
        private var _userInputtedRetirementAge = mutableIntStateOf(0)

How do i replace the 0 with the viewstate(API) value?

I'm not sure what the purpose of ModellerSharedData is and how that is related to your composable, but to me the easiest way to solve the issue seems to be use a view model like this:
class MyViewModel(/*...*/) : ViewModel() {
    private val userInputtedRetirementAge = MutableStateFlow<Int?>(null)

    val viewState: StateFlow<UiState> = combine(
        personalProjectionsRepository.projectionsStateFlow,
        userInputtedRetirementAge,
    ) { repo, user ->
        UiState(repo.age, user)
    }.stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
        initialValue = UiState(),
    )

    fun setRetirementAge(age: Int) {
        userInputtedRetirementAge.value = age
    }
}

With this state holder:
data class UiState(
    val initialRetirementAge: Int = 0,
    val userInputtedRetirementAge: Int? = null,
)

That holds the two data points (initial age, user provided age) as flows and combines them into a UiState object that is exposed as a StateFlow. You can simply collect that flow in your composable and then determine what to display:
val uiState by viewModel.viewState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
val retirementAge = uiState.userInputtedRetirementAge ?: uiState.initialRetirementAge

MakeChangeCard(
    cardTitle = R.string.retirement_age_screen_title,
    editLinkText = R.string.edit_link,
    cardContent = "$retirementAge",
    onCardClick = onRetirementCardClick,
    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
)

Just make sure to call the view model's setRetirementAge whenever the user entered a new value.

Heyya! The object that you're referencing handles passing the user entered data from one screen to another - the data is entered by the user on one screen and then displayed on another - the code that i've added above does that job but unfortunately the starting data will always be 0 since i've hardcoded it - it should not be 0, is should be whatever is fetched from the api @Leviathan

Well, the API takes some time to fetch the data, so the UI cannot display that from the start, it needs to display something else until that value is available. You can declare the initial age as val initialRetirementAge: Int? = null to distinguish the case where the API hasn't yet provided a value. If you don't want to display a 0 then display whatever else you want in this case, like a CircularProgressIndicator(), for example. As soon as the API delivers its value your UI then automatically updates and displays that new value.

I use this method for api and it works :
sealed class ApiState{
object Loading : ApiState()
class Failure(val msg:Throwable) : ApiState()
class Success(val data:Any) : ApiState()
object Empty : ApiState()

}
private val chargeCreateOrderFlow: MutableStateFlow<ApiState> = MutableStateFlow(ApiState.Empty)
val _chargeCreateOrderFlow: StateFlow<ApiState> = chargeCreateOrderFlow

        fun chargeOrder(url: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    chargeCreateOrderFlow.value = ApiState.Loading
    chargeRepository.chargeOrder(url)
        .catch { e ->
            chargeCreateOrderFlow.value = ApiState.Failure(e)
        }.collect { data ->
            chargeCreateOrderFlow.value = ApiState.Success(data)
        }
}


Can you explain how this relates to the question? This just looks like an unrelated code dump, not an answer.
